# Format of datetime in pyplot axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data against a list of `datetime` objects in the x axis with pyplot. However the dates appear as the standard format, which is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` (way too long). I can circumvent this by creating a list of date strings with `strftime` and use that instead. I also know that there is some kind of `date` object intrinsic for `pyplot` which I could use instead of `datetime`.

Is there a way to tell `pyplot` in which format to plot the `datetime`objects however? Without having to transform everything to string or another kind of object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `DateFormatter`:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(your_dates, your_data)

# format your data to desired format. Here I chose YYYY-MM-DD but you can set it to whatever you want.
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))

# rotate and align the tick labels so they look better
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Answer (score 19):

Apart from manually specifying the datetime format for the axes as shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29968750/4124317), you may use [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) to set the format.

The standard is

> ```
> # date.autoformatter.year     : %Y
> # date.autoformatter.month    : %Y-%m
> # date.autoformatter.day      : %Y-%m-%d
> # date.autoformatter.hour     : %m-%d %H
> # date.autoformatter.minute   : %d %H:%M
> # date.autoformatter.second   : %H:%M:%S
> # date.autoformatter.microsecond   : %M:%S.%f
> ```

You may change that in the [matplotlib rc file](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html),
 or inside the code via

```
plt.rcParams["date.autoformatter.minute"] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Unlike the downvote might suggest, this method is working nicely and even saves some typing compared to other options.

Comment: I agree, this is totally sufficient to solve the issue.

Comment: What is the library used for `date.autoformatter`?

Comment: The other answer didn't work for me, this is the only one that has worked.