# Python - Matplotlibs - How to format and add interval to X axis which has date and times?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data that looks like below. The `Date/Time` field is in `%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S` format.

```
           Date/Time  Utilization
 04-01-2020 10:00:00           10
 04-01-2020 10:10:00           20
 04-01-2020 10:20:00           50
 04-01-2020 10:30:00           10
 04-02-2020 15:30:00           20
 04-02-2020 15:40:00           10
 04-02-2020 15:50:00           10
 04-07-2020 23:40:00           40
 04-07-2020 23:50:00           50
```

I want to plot this in Matplotlib, with x-axis as the date/time and y-axis as the utilization.

When I plot this, each  of these 10 minute intervals are all squished together in the X-Axis (screenshot  below):
[image]

My code for above is this:

```
def plot_graph(utilization_map):
    utilization_array = []
    date_array = []
    for each_time in utilization_map:
        utilization = utilization_map[each_time]
        utilization_array.append(utilization)
        human_time = convert_epoch_to_datetime_for_plots(each_time) # This converts the epoch time in %m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S format
        date_array.append(human_time)
    x_axis = date_array
    y_axis = utilization_array
    plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, color='b')
    plt.title("Utilization")
    plt.xlabel("Days")
    plt.ylabel("Percent of Utilization")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

**Question:** I want to plot it in a way that the X-axis labels show only in `%m-%d` or `%m-%d-%Y` format and with daily intervals instead of 10 minutes, so all the times are not mushed  together in the X-axis. How do I do this?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html

Comment: Related: [Changing the formatting of a datetime axis in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib) ... [Format of datetime in pyplot axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968654/format-of-datetime-in-pyplot-axis)  ... Many more searching with variants of `python matplotlib x axis date format site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: The code provided is your function, but this is not reproducible code, in that you haven't included everything required to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to combine the data from 10 minutes to daily and then plot it.

  - `pd.DataFrame(df['util'].resample('D').sum())`

### imports

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
```

### create reproducible dataframe

```py
dates = pd.date_range(start='2014-04-01', end='2020-04-07', freq='10min').tolist()

np.random.seed(0) 
utilization = [np.random.randint(10, 50) for _ in range(len(dates))]


df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'util': utilization})
df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)


                     util
dates                    
2014-04-01 00:00:00    26
2014-04-01 00:10:00    44
2014-04-01 00:20:00    36
2014-04-01 00:30:00    13
2014-04-01 00:40:00    41
2014-04-01 00:50:00    30
2014-04-01 01:00:00    21
2014-04-01 01:10:00    10
2014-04-01 01:20:00    25
2014-04-01 01:30:00    18
```

### resample dataframe to daily

```py
df_daily = pd.DataFrame(df['util'].resample('D').sum())

            util
dates           
2014-04-01  4096
2014-04-02  4338
2014-04-03  4194
2014-04-04  4186
2014-04-05  4262
2014-04-06  4342
2014-04-07  4101
2014-04-08  4445
2014-04-09  4346
2014-04-10  4378
```

### plot the dataframe

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(df_daily.index, df_daily['util'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

- This data is random from `numpy` so all the average sums are about 4200, for this example.