# Convert time stamps for matplotlib for data visualisation

Tags: matplotlib

I have a x axis with time stamps and y axis have some int values provided values below.
I'm trying to plot a graph with x and y values using matplotlib

I've tried below code, which does not work. Can someone please help me with this

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import pandas as pd

X = []

for i in x:
    tim = datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    dat = date2num(t)
    X.append(dat)

print(X)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(X,y)
plt.show()
```

and also tried this below code from stack overflow

[Format of datetime in pyplot axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968654/format-of-datetime-in-pyplot-axis)

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(X, y)

# format your data to desired format. Here I chose YYYY-MM-DD but you can set it to whatever you want.
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))

# rotate and align the tick labels so they look better
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image: Please find the output in screenshot]

```
x = ['2020-04-26 19:28:40.136', '2020-04-26 19:28:39.970', '2020-04-26 19:28:37.670', '2020-04-26 19:27:46.196', '2020-04-26 19:27:45.852', '2020-04-26 19:27:43.740', '2020-04-26 19:27:13.641', '2020-04-26 19:26:22.070', '2020-04-26 19:26:19.783', '2020-04-26 19:02:50.721', '2020-04-26 19:02:49.504', '2020-04-26 19:02:49.192', '2020-04-26 18:57:47.572', '2020-04-26 18:14:26.204']

y = ['2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0']
```

After converting y to int as suggested. I'm able to plot the metrics. But, unable to see timestamps in metrics as shown below

[image: Output after changing y to int]

Comment: Is your `y` data string-type or numerical?

Comment: its a list, should be numeric

Comment: What printed out is **NOT** numeric. Also, `matplotlib` handles `datetime` just fine, do `plot(x,y)` instead of `plot(X,y)`.

Comment: add `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` after `plt.plot(x, y)`.