# Increment x and y values with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this graph where my x and y values look like a mess. I believe that is due to the fact that all of the values are bunched together being as there's 552 of them. I simplified the x values to just the month and year which spread out the x values better, however I think that's the cause of why the graph looks like a staircase instead of linear:

[image: current graph]

This is my code. I only used `matplotlib` to graph and `SQL` to help organize the data from [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/main/data/countries-aggregated.csv) csv file. How can I simplify my x and y values?

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cs50 import SQL
import datetime

def make_list(query, thelist, key): # format list so not dict
    for i in query:
        thelist.append(i[key])
    return thelist

plt.title("Covid Cases")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Number of Cases")

# Each date has the countries' case reports

db = SQL("sqlite:///data.db")

# create list of dates for x axis
datesDict = db.execute("SELECT Date FROM countries WHERE Country = 'Afghanistan'")
dates = []
dates = make_list(datesDict, dates, 'Date')
for i in range(len(dates)): # format date
    dates[i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[i], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%b %Y")

# create list of confirmed cases
select_country = "United Kingdom"
find_confirmed = db.execute("SELECT Confirmed FROM countries WHERE Country = ?", select_country)
confirmed = []
confirmed = make_list(find_confirmed, confirmed, "Confirmed")

# plot
plt.plot(dates, confirmed, color = "red")
plt.show()
```

Comment: This happens when the data are strings. Here the dates are definitely strings due to `strftime`. Keep the dates as actual `datetime` objects and use [`matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b %Y')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29968750/13138364).

Comment: You should also double check if the SQL results are strings or numerics.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's looking much nicer. Where should I put `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b %Y')`? The spacing looks good right now but it's showing YYYY-MM instead of something like Jan 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the data are strings.

1. I'm not sure about the SQL data, but they look like strings based on your figure output. Convert them to floats, e.g. in the `make_list` function:

   ```py
   thelist.append(float(i[key]))
   ```
2. The dates are definitely strings due to `strftime`, so remove the `strftime` to keep the dates as real `datetime` objects:

   ```py
   for i in range(len(dates)):
       dates[i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[i], '%Y-%m-%d')
   ```
3. Add a [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) and [`autofmt_xdate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) after the plotting command:

   ```py
   import matplotlib.dates as mdates

   plt.plot(dates, confirmed, color='red')
   plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %Y'))
   plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

   plt.show()
   ```